# Java replace word in curly braces by name

Tags: java, android

I have a string like:

```java
String message = "This is a message for {ID_PW}. Your result is {exam_result}. Please quote {ID_PW} if replying";
```

I am importing data from CSV that I would like to use to replace the items between curly braces.

```java
// Using OpenCSV to read in CSV...code omitted for brevity
values = (Map<String, String>) reader.readMap();
// values has 'ID_PW', 'exam_result', etc keys
```

How can I replace the items in curly braces in the `message` with the equivalent value of the key in `values`?

Comment: By writing code. Why don't you start by trying with just `ID_PW`. How would you replace `{ID_PW}` in your `String` with any other value - let's say "literally"? Try to write that code and then apply the pattern to your current problem. If you get stuck, show us that attempt and I think someone will gladly help you (I will if no one else will).

Comment: And then try to extract the values using a regex (think about what *definitely* isn't allowed in between curly braces).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Nothing like a good kick up the backside (probably what I needed). I've added an answer - would appreciate it if you'd review it as I am very new to Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
String message = "This is a message for {ID_PW}. Your result is {exam_result}. Please quote {ID_PW} if replying";

LinkedHashSet<String> fields = new LinkedHashSet<>();  // 'Automatically' handle duplicates

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(message);

// Find 'fields' in the message that are wrapped in curly braces and add to hash set
while (m.find()) {
    fields.add((m.group(1)));
}

// Go through CSV and parse the message with the associated fields
while (((values = (Map<String, String>) reader.readMap())) != null)
{
    Iterator itr = fields.iterator();
    String newMsg = message;
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        String field = (String) itr.next();
        String value = values.get(field);
        if(value != null) {
            newMsg = newMsg.replaceAll("\\{" + field + "\\}", value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for:

```
String s = "I bought {0,number,integer} mangos. From {1}, the fruit seller. Out of them {2,number,percent} were bad.";
MessageFormat formatter = new MessageFormat(s);
Object[] argz = {22, "John", 0.3};
System.out.println(formatter.format(argz));
```

This outputs:

```
I bought 22 mangos. From John, the fruit seller. Out of them 30% were bad.
```

Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringBuilder`. `StringBuilder` is explicitly designed to be a mutable type of `String`. Next, don't use regular expressions in a loop. Regular expressions can be powerful, but since you will be using a loop to search for multiple patterns there is nothing regular involved (multiple patterns means multiple expressions).

I would just search left to right for `{` and then `}` extract the `key` and search for it in the `values` map. Something like,

```
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("ID_PW", "SimpleOne");
values.put("exam_result", "84");
String message = "This is a message for {ID_PW}. Your result "
        + "is {exam_result}. Please quote {ID_PW} if replying";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(message);
int p = -1;
while ((p = sb.indexOf("{", p + 1)) > -1) {
    int e = sb.indexOf("}", p + 1);
    if (e > -1) {
        String key = sb.substring(p + 1, e);
        if (values.containsKey(key)) {
            sb.replace(p, p + key.length() + 2, values.get(key));
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Outputs

```
This is a message for SimpleOne. Your result is 84. Please quote SimpleOne if replying
```